# Show that the tangent plan pass through the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Show that all the tangent plans to the conic surface $z = xf(\frac{y}{x})$ at the point $M(x_o,y_o,z_o)$, where $x_o \neq 0$, pass through the origin of the cordinates

First, I've found the tangent plan at this generic point $M$ of the surface:

$z - z_o = (x-x_o)(f(\frac{x_o}{y_o}) - x_o \frac{y_o}{x_o^2}f'_x(\frac{y_o}{x_o})) + (y-y_o)(x_o \frac{1}{x_o} f'_y(\frac{y_o}{x_o}))$

We want to check if $(0,0,0)$ is a point of this plan. Then:

$-z_o = -x_o f(\frac{y_o}{x_o}) + y_o f'_x(\frac{y_o}{x_o}) - y_o f'_y(\frac{y_o}{x_o})$

But I couldn't prove that this equality holds (i.e,$ y_o f'_y(\frac{y_o}{x_o}) = y_o f'_x(\frac{y_o}{x_o})$)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you say that it's a conic surface ? See the graphical representation I have provided in my answer to the same question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2121925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense an apparent misconception on your part regarding the term $f(y/x)$. This is hiding a second function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x,y) = f(y/x)$, with $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. (Possibly not all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}$, in which case just assume they are defined for the largest subset avaiable for the exercise.)

Therefore, expressions as $f'_y$ and $f'_x$ don't make much sense, because $f$ is not a function of two variables, but $g$, as we defined it, is.

Calculating the partial derivatives of $z$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  & = f \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) + x f' \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) \left( - \frac{1}{x^2} \right) = f \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) - \frac{y}{x} f' \left( \frac{y}{x} \right), \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} & = x f' \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) \frac{1}{x} = f' \left( \frac{y}{x} \right).
\end{align}$$

Notice also that $z_0 = x_0 f(y_0/x_0)$. Putting it all together in the tangent plane equation, we have

$$z - x_0 f \left( \frac{y_0}{x_0} \right) = \left( f \left( \frac{y_0}{x_0} \right) - \frac{y_0}{x_0} f' \left( \frac{y_0}{x_0} \right) \right) (x - x_0) + \left( f' \left( \frac{y_0}{x_0} \right) \right) (y-y_0).$$

Expand out and you'll simplify it down to

$$z = \left( f \left( \frac{y_0}{x_0} \right) - \frac{y_0}{x_0} f' \left( \frac{y_0}{x_0} \right) \right) x + \left( f' \left( \frac{y_0}{x_0} \right) \right) y.$$

We see then that $x=y=z=0$ is a solution to this plane equation and therefore it passes through the origin.