# On what condition the intersection of all tangent planes of the surface $z = y f(\frac{x}{y})$ is $\{ (0, 0, 0) \}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

#### Problem

Suppose $f \in C^1$, $A$ is the intersection of all tangent planes of the surface $z = y f(\frac{x}{y})$. Under what condition, we have $A = \{ (0, 0, 0) \}$ ? That is, to find a set $F$, s.t. $A = \{ (0, 0, 0) \} \Leftrightarrow f \in F$.

#### Analysis

The fact that $(0, 0, 0) \in A$ is discussed sufficently at [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694143/show-that-all-tangent-planes-of-the-graph-of-g-intersect-in-a-common-point), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574572/show-that-the-tangent-plan-pass-through-the-origin), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121925/show-that-all-the-tangent-planes-to-the-surface-z-yf-fracxy-pass-throu?rq=1).

I can come up with a trival example to show that there's $f \not\in F$: if $f \equiv 0$, $A = \{ (x, y, 0) | x, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

#### Acknowledge

This is a question derived from a Calculus exercise. But I think answering it may need more difficult math. So I come here to ask for some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we define$$g(x,y,z)\triangleq z-yf({x\over y})=0$$therefore $$g_x(x,y,z)=-f'({x\over y})\\g_y(x,y,z)=-f({x\over y})+{x\over y}f'({x\over y})\\g_z(x,y,z)=1$$Now, by geometry and calculus and the definition of the gradient vector, we now that and plane tangent on $g(x,y,z)=0$ in $(a,b,c)$ **is perpendicular to $\nabla g(a,b,c)$**. This leads to the following general equation of planes:$$-f'\left({a\over b}\right)(x-a)+\left[-f\left({a\over b}\right)+{a\over b}f'\left({a\over b}\right)\right](y-b)+z-c=0$$Now we obtain a very interesting fact. After simplification, the general equation, reduces to:$$-f'\left({a\over b}\right)x+\left[-f\left({a\over b}\right)+{a\over b}f'\left({a\over b}\right)\right]y+z=0$$which **always crosses the origin**. If we define $u\triangleq{a\over b}$, we should go looking for functions, $f$, such that $$\underbrace{\text{Span}}_{u\in \Bbb R}\Bigg[\Big(-f'(u),-f(u)+uf'(u),1\Big)\Bigg]=\Bbb R^3$$Instead, we study cases such that the vector $\Big(-f'(u),-f(u)+uf'(u),1\Big)$ can be imaged by **at most 2 independent vectors** i.e. $$\Big(-f'(u),-f(u)+uf'(u),1\Big)=k_1(u)(p_1,q_1,r_1)+k_2(u)(p_2,q_2,r_2)$$This requires that **a linear combination of the components of the vector be zero**, i.e. we can find coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that$$-\alpha f'(u)+(-f(u)+uf'(u))\beta+\gamma=0$$After solving the outcome differential equation, the possible functions $f(u)$ are $$f(u)=\epsilon u+\zeta$$where $\epsilon ,\zeta$ are real constants. Therefore $$F^c=\{\text{the set of linear functions}\}$$and

> $$f(x) \text{ is }\textbf{not} \text{ a linear function}\iff A=\{(0,0,0)\}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But some steps are a little difficult for me to understand. Could you please explain more detailedly: Why should we go for functions such that $\mathrm{Span}[...] = \mathbb{R}^3$? Why the vector can be imaged by at most 2 independent vectors? Why this requires that a linear combination of the components of the vector be zero? Thank you again!

Comment: Your welcome. Sure I'll explain! The first thing is that if the characteristic vectors of all the tangent planes don't span $\Bbb R^3$, then they must span a lower subspace e.g. $\Bbb R$. Furthermore, if they span a 1-dimensional subspace, then they all must be a multiple of one vector which leads to parallel planes. The parallel planes common in one point (origin) **must be equal** and to that reason, $A\ne\{(0,0,0)\}$. In this case, $A$ becomes a plane (more precisely, the same tangent plane). A similar case happens when the vectors span a 2-dimensional subspace where $A $ (to be continued)

Comment: (cont'd) becomes a line as the intersection of all the tangent planes. Now, when has a subspace a dimension equal to $k$? When the most general form of the vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of **$k$ independent vectors**.

Comment: Thanks! After finally understanding your proof, I have a little advice: maybe we could directly jump to the differential equation, because if $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \not= 0 \in A$, then all the normal vectors of the tangent planes are orthogonal to $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, i.e., $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \cdot (-f'(u), -f(u) + uf'(u), 1) = 0$.

Comment: Your welcome. Cheers! Another (shorter) way of implying linear independence.